New light switch - 2 black & 2 red wires
Trying to put in a dimmer.  It will control 4 lights, and is 1 of 3 switches that control these 4 lights.  This one switch will be the only dimmer.
Here’s what is currently installed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wdo8tuRfua38F4hMJYlB5htwTB9lGYB/view?usp=drivesdk
And here is the new dimmer:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10r6mQHlB4dK5OHYXcyJXdob6gkzZZ2Ya/view?usp=drivesdk
Not sure how the original wiring will work with new wires.

TL;DR It Won't Work
What you currently have is a 4-Way Switch. That means it is the middle switch of at least 3 switches that control a set of lights. A sample diagram from Wikipedia:

Each of the 3-way switches on the ends can switch a common wire to one or the other of two travelers. The 4-way switch in the middle (and there can even be more than one 4-way switch) switches between pairs of travelers. The result is that at any time any switch can be flipped to turn the circuit on if it is off or off if it is on.
The problem is that a dimmer normally has just one "in" (hot or line) and one "out" (switched hot or load). Some dimmers can function as a 3-way switch, but I have not seen any that can function as a 4-way switch. Even as a 3-way switch, there may be other requirements - either having to be the first switch (and not the last) or the last switch (and not the first) or requiring a neutral.
All of which means that:

A typical dimmer (or timer or motion sensor or smart switch) will not work as a direct 4-way switch replacement.
You may be able to install this dimmer (or a timer, etc.) to replace one of the 3-way switches.
If you install this dimmer (or a timer, etc.) to replace one of the 3-way switches, it may or may not be compatible with the 4-way switch and it may or may not require some rewiring of the 4-way switch and/or the other 3-way switch.
If you want to actually control the dimming (not just on/off) from more than one location then you will need smart switches, as you can only have one ordinary dimmer on a circuit - two dimmers will cause serious problems.

